# Управление View фрагмента из Activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Сделал как примере, до вкладок, вкладки не нужны:

https://habrahabr.ru/post/236567/

Но там не подсказали для новичков как теперь обратиться к элементам в фрагменте. Читал примеры, пробовал, но что то идет не так. Может проблема что примеры для андроид выше v4.

Как теперь обратиться к элементам которые в фрагменте screen_one? Как например обработать в NumberPicker и установить минимальные и максимальные значения и обработать событие OnValueChangeListener из mainActivity?

Понимаю что для новичков, но не могу понять. Читал примеры обращения из главной активности к фрагменту, но к данному конкретному случаю применить не получается...

Как обратиться из самого фрагмента я разобрался:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.screen_one, container, false);
  //  numberPicker.findViewById(R.id.light_on_hour);
    NumberPicker light_on_hours = (NumberPicker) rootView.findViewById(R.id.light_on_hour);
    light_on_hours.setEnabled(true);
    light_on_hours.setMinValue(0);
    light_on_hours.setMaxValue(23);
    light_on_hours.setValue(10);

    return rootView;
}
```

Подскажите как из активности обращаться и листенеры в активности перехватывать или передавать в активность. И как из активности менять значения.

Comment: Вообще это не очень хорошая практика, делать какую либо бизнес логику в активити. Почитайте про шаблоны проэктирования типа MVP. А по поводу вашего вопроса, совсем не самый лучший подход(по этому и не пишу его в ответах), в любом фрагменте вы можете вызвать метод getActivity(), который даст вам объект Аctivity  в котором он расположен. Если вы его прикастите к конкретно к тому активити ((MainActivity) getActivity).useSomeMethod(), то сможете вызывать методы вашего рут активити, сетить туда данные и т.д... Но ещё раз скажу, делать бизнес логику в активити это очень "неочень" подход.

Comment: Ещё можно создать в активити колбек и передать его во фрагмент при его создании. Или воспользоваться сторонними библиотеками типа EventBus.

Comment: @Eugene Troyanskii, уточню. У меня в MainActivity есть callback в который приходят и обрабатываются сообщения извне(mqtt) так вот в случае прихода определенного сообщения мне нужно менять визуальный элемент в фрагменте. То есть мне нужно из MainActivity обращаться в фрагменты. Только тут как я понимаю фрагменты в данном примере динамически подгружаются когда происходит  private void selectItem(int position) { где то здесь fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(content_frame, fragment).commit();  Вообще можно так сделать в данном случае из MainActivity?

Comment: Можно через фрагмент менеджер обратиться к фрагменту(если он в него добавлен). А вообще вы можете при создании фрагмента в автивити сохранить ссылку на его объект(сделать глобальную переменную) и потом делать с ней все что захотите))

Comment: @ Eugene Troyanskii Я так понял тут все про это написано подробно, для таких как я))))  http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/fragment2.php

Answer (score 1):

Все, разобрался. Если привязываться к конкретно данному примеру ссылка на который сверху, то чтобы вызвать элемент View из фрагмента(пример для NumberPicker):

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.screen_one, container, false);
  //  numberPicker.findViewById(R.id.light_on_hour);
    NumberPicker light_on_hours = (NumberPicker) rootView.findViewById(R.id.light_on_hour);
    light_on_hours.setEnabled(true);
    light_on_hours.setMinValue(0);
    light_on_hours.setMaxValue(23);
    light_on_hours.setValue(10);

    return rootView;
}
```

Если из активности:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
ScreenOne screen_one = (ScreenOne) fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.content_frame);

if (screen_one != null){
((TextView) screen_one.getView().findViewById(R.id.text_light_on))
                                                    .setText("Access to Fragment 1 from Activity");

 }
```